# angular application build in electron print a div shows blank window

Tags: angular, electron

I have developed an angular application then I build that application in an electron. The application works fine but when I click the button to print specific div it opens a blank window of the electron. I use `ngx-print` library. it works great with angular serve but got a problem with electron build.

```
<button class="btn btn-raised mr-1 shadow-z-2 btn-success"  
printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>
   print
</button>

<div id="print-section"> Print This</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but default behaviour of a button is to submit a form - that could be happening? Try putting `type="button"` on the button

Comment: no it wont help

Comment: do you have any errors? What means " got a problem with electron build": button not work, not a build etc&?

Comment: basically, I use ngx-print to print a div and it works fine when I run the angular app but when I build in the electron (same angular app) the print does not work. it shows a blank window. tell me if you didn't get it I'll upload screenshots. thanks for considering my question.

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-desktop-electron
try to check if u did everything as described in this section. A problem you are describing it's not about a 3-party library but there should be some problem with electron configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in ngx-print code we have this part to do this:

```
printContents = document.getElementById(this.printSectionId).innerHTML;
popupWin = window.open('_blank', '', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write("\n      <html>\n        <head>\n          <title>" + (this.printTitle ? this.printTitle : '') + "</title>\n          <style>\n            " + this.returnStyleValues() + "\n          </style>\n        </head>\n    <body onload=\"window.print();window.close()\">" + printContents + "</body>\n      </html>");
popupWin.document.close();
```

when electron tries to open new window it opens a `BrowserWindowProxy` so after that if it tries to access popupWin.document it get's undefined and shows error.
we can tell electron to open a native window to access the open of it and the access to document, so in your `main.js` or `main.ts` you can try:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    webPreferences: {
      nativeWindowOpen: true, // add this
      nodeIntegration: false
    }
 });
```

then the electron will new a native window. then in the ngx-print code the

```
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
```

should be:

```
popupWin = window.open('_blank', '', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
```

to open a new blank page.
you can read more about `webPreferences` in https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window.

Comment: thanks for at least considering my question. I am gonna try this to my code.i really appreciate your effort.

Comment: but I don't have any code of ngx print. it is a library approach . should I use pure javascript print code for printing and really, Please don't mind I don't know what to do with the changes you told me I am blank with these updates

Comment: Hey, you got it. Thank You very much. I think you didn't notice that "I am keeping talking to you by comment .." it means I am hungry for this solution, I searched for it but maybe my expertise level or my Query is not capable of it. I see this was so simple but still, I lost it in my search. Ahh, anyhow. Thanks A lot. it seems funny to talk here like this but may b I post this that's why I owe this privilege to talk here like this. it seems like a paragraph and I keep talking like a mad. Don't laugh I am gonna end this. I am such a freak.

Comment: Heyy:))) you're welcome. I changed the library code from my node modules ngx-print bundled codes. But you can fork the ngx-print make your changes and use your own forked of project or open an issue in their github  to solve the related problems.

Comment: heyy :)) i works but not that much i want , it through a blank div i mean it didn't took the div i reference to print it through a blank div and printer took the page blank out tell me the way to help . really appreciated if you consider . please

Comment: do you change the popupWin?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have tried this and yeah it works, but the electron app crashes when clicking print button. any resolution for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, @FatemeFazli, can you please give some suggestion on this. I badly need this.